# Python is changing datatype from str/float to tuple

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am running into a problem where assignment in python is changing datatype:

code

```
# creating list from tuple
newitem = list(item) 
# assignment is done here
m100_productBrand                   = newitem[8],
print "type(item)" , type(item)
print "type(newitem)" , type(newitem)
print "newitem" , newitem
print "newitem[8] : " , newitem[8] , type(newitem[8])
print "m100_productBrand: " , m100_productBrand , type(m100_productBrand)
```

Output

```
type(item) <type 'tuple'>
type(newitem) <type 'list'>
newitem ['MOBEFMMWJVUE5ZKB', 'New Model:Good Ear phone', 'A&K G 4040(Black)', 890.0, 890.0, '', 'https://someurl', 10.0, 'A&K', '1', 990.0, 'Mobiles>Handsets', 'https://someurl', 'https://someurl', 'https://someurl', '1', 'Mobile, Battery, Charger, Earphone', '', 'G 4040', 'Black', 'Feature Phones', 'Dual Sim', 2.4, '320 x 480 Pixels', 'HVGA', '', '', '', 32.0, 32.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'Yes', '', '', 'GSM, GSM', '', '', '', 'Yes', '3.5 mm', 'Normal', '', 1050.0, '1 Year Manufacturer Warranty']
    newitem[8] :  A&K <type 'str'>
    m100_productBrand:  ('A&K',) <type 'tuple'>
```

I am confused as why m100_productBrand is turning into tuple even though newitem[8] is string.

**Additional info:**

1. when I run the same code python command line environment it works
   fine.
2. Is this issue coming because I had created newitem from tuple 
   using list(item) ?

Comment: `newitem[8],` is a tuple. See the comma.

Comment: Putting a comma after something makes it a tuple with one element.

Comment: I rerun the code by removing the comma and its working fine.
Thanks for your help.
`m100_productBrand                   = newitem[8]`
Output
`newitem[8] :  A&K <type 'str'>
m100_productBrand:  A&K <type 'str'>`

Comment: @user2357112 Can you add you response as answer instead of comment ? I will mark it as "Answer" ?

Answer (score 2):

coma should not be present after newitem[8]

correct code is:

```
# creating list from tuple
newitem = list(item) 
# assignment is done here
m100_productBrand = newitem[8]
print "type(item)" , type(item)
print "type(newitem)" , type(newitem)
print "newitem" , newitem
print "newitem[8] : " , newitem[8] , type(newitem[8])
print "m100_productBrand: " , m100_productBrand , type(m100_productBrand)
```